# How do I change unknown properties in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've recently decided to make a tweening/easing library in C#. I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to create a wrapper class in order to modify objects, but rather, modify them directly from the library. In simple words, I'm trying to do this:

```
string Property = "Text"; //This is not always going to be "Text", obviously.
label1[Property] = "New Text"; //An equivalent of label1.Text = "New Text";
```

How can I do that, or is it possible at all?

Comment: Reflect over the object, and store its properties in a dictionary.

Comment: you could think of using automappers

Comment: there are plenty of disadvantages, and I don't see how it can be called "easing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a Dictionary to store your data, possibly wired up to properties:

```
class Whatever{
  Dictionary<string, string> _props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  public string FirstName {
    get => _props[nameof(FirstName)];
    set => _props[nameof(FirstName)] = value;
  }

  public IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames => _props.Keys;

  public string this[string n] {
    get => _props[n];
    set => _props[n] = value;
  }
}
```

Now you can either use your named properties (`myWhatever.FirstName = "John"`) or you can use access to the dictionary to store any name you want (`myWhatever["hello"] = "goodbye"`), and you can enumerate it to get any custom names in addition to the ones you coded in as properties of the class.

The `nameof` is usedful to get the compiler to supply the string name of the FirstName property - it means you can refactor the code in future and it will change as part of the auto refactor in VS, rather than being a hardcoded string that will go out of sync during a VS-assisted rename of the property (Ctrl-R,R)